# tftp server client example for lpc1768

Tags: c, ftp, embedded, lpc, tftp

I am trying to work a TFTP client for transferring files in MMC/SD card to PC through Ethernet on LPC1768 controller. For TFTP, it needs two ports to be connected to TFTP server.
I am using TCP/IP stack which comes with LPC1768 webserver example. Is it possible to open two ports at a time.. I tried but its not working.

Is there any sample program or tutorial for TFTP client for microcontrollers which can work without OS?
or any alternative protocols?

Comment: Does it work with only one port? *"I tried but its not working."* is not helpful; How is it not working?

Comment: my pc acts as a server and my lpc1768 controller board acts as a client,i am trying to send file from pc to my board using tftp over lan network,until now i am unable to find anything in this direction,i am looking for any sample example that tries to accomplish this task.

Comment: Have you tried lwip? They have a tutorial to implement for Bare Metal: http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Porting_For_Bare_Metal

Comment: You might try being more explicit about the code you are using, a link to the example you mentioned for instance and who's stack library you are using. Respond by improving your question rather than adding a comment - this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Your title says TFTP but your question body says FTP.  Which are you actually going to use?